# How to Insert values from Postman (json type) to Postgres using Gorm (go struct)

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to code some simple CRUD focused in employees management, but in this point I'm a little confused so how I should to use struct attributes `json:...` and `gorm:` for declaring specific data types and constraints to the new database table and specific values sended in json format from Postman. Are you working with Go-Gorm?

```
//db file
package tiposDocumentos

import (
    "bitbucket.org/username/repositoryname/db"
    "bitbucket.org/username/repositoryname/models"
)

// Inserta un nuevo tipo de documento en la base de datos.
func InsertTipoDocumento(tp models.TiposDocumentos) (bool, error) {
    db.PsqlDb.AutoMigrate(&tp)
    if db.PsqlDb.NewRecord(tp) {
        err := db.PsqlDb.Create(&tp)
        if err != nil {
            return false, nil
        }
    } else {
        return false, errors.New("clave primaria se encuentra en uso")
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

```
package models
    
type TiposDocumentos struct {
        TdoCodigo       string  `json:"tdo_codigo" gorm:"column:tdo_codigo;type:varchar(3);PRIMARY_KEY;AUTO_INCREMENT:false"`
        TdoDescripcion  string  `json:"tdo_descripcion" gorm:"column:tdo_descripcion;type:varchar(50)"`
        TdoCodigoAfip   string  `json:"tdo_codigo_afip" gorm:"column:tdo_codigo_afip;type:varchar(10)"`
}
```

```
package routers

import (
    "bitbucket.org/username/repositoryname/db/tiposDocumentos"
    "bitbucket.org/username/repositoryname/models"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    tp models.TiposDocumentos
)

// Valida registro recibido y lo inserta en la base de datos.
func PostTiposDocuemntos(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&tp)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    estado, err := tiposDocumentos.InsertTipoDocumento(tp)
    if estado == false {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
}
```

In this point, after send the request from Postman the program create successfully the table and its specifications and retrieve code 201 but the record was not inserted in the table.
[image]
View from pgAdmin4
[image]

Thanks ☻

Error after insert sucesfuly a new record in the database:

```
2020/07/13 12:43:28 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:64546: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 36 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000230d20)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1772 +0x140
panic(0x8085e0, 0xbb5e20)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x3f1
bitbucket.org/emanuelvald/gestion_personal/routers.PostTiposDocuemntos(0x912c20, 0xc00005e000, 0xc000058200)
        C:/Projects/Go/src/bitbucket.org/emanuelvald/gestion_personal/routers/tiposDocumentos.go:44 +0x151
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x893498, 0x912c20, 0xc00005e000, 0xc000058200)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2012 +0x4b
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc00022a0c0, 0x912c20, 0xc00005e000, 0xc000058000)
        C:/Projects/Go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0xe9
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000270000, 0x912c20, 0xc00005e000, 0xc000058000)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2807 +0xaa
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000230d20, 0x9137a0, 0xc000038080)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1895 +0x873
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2933 +0x363
```

Comment: When this `if db.PsqlDb.NewRecord(tp) {` is not satisfied you are returning `true, nil` which you then interpret as "everything went well" even though it obviously did *not*. Fix the logic first.

Comment: I fixed this problem and the the NewRecord function return false as if primary key was used but the table is empty!!!

Comment: I comment the NewRecord line and now the record was inserted in the table but the program return a new error 2020/07/13 12:43:28 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:64546: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 36 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000230d20)

Comment: Add the full stack trace of the panic to the question and I'll point out the exact file and line that's causing the crash. But if I had to guess, gorm `Create` returns the `*DB` instance and not an error, so the `err` variable is always a non-nil `*DB`, and therefore `if err != nil {` is always satisfied... then in that branch you return `false, nil` and subsequently you have the caller invoke `err.Error()` on that `nil` error value and boom!

Comment: The proper way to check gorm errors is to inspect the `Error` field of the `*DB` instance. i.e. `err := db.Create(&tp).Error` and then if `err` is not `nil`, you need to return it to the caller `return false, err`.

Comment: I pasted the error lineas in the question. I didn't know about function Error in Create! Thanks :)

Comment: The stack trace shows that the origin of the panic is coming from the `routers.PostTiposDocuemntos` function in file `...routers/tiposDocumentos.go` on line `44`.

Comment: Thanks for your help mkopriva. I will read more about gorm errors handler. See you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens when err is non-nil here:

```
 if err != nil {
     return false, nil
 }
```

and then you do this:

```
estado, err := tiposDocumentos.InsertTipoDocumento(tp)
if estado == false {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

So, `estado` is false, and then you try to access `err.Error()`, but `err` is `nil`, so you get a

```
invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

You probably just need to do:

```
 if err != nil {
     return false, err
 }
```

and then do:

```
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dave, I fixed my code with your help. Now I can insert new records in my CRUD project and I don't retrieve errors. See you!!!

Comment: @YoungAlCapone if possible try to follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, I forgot  accept your answer. Thanks again :)